# Issue with json Content type for DeepInsert

Tags: java, json, odata, rest-client

I'm trying deepinsert with Json on the service,http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/OData/OData.svc/Categories with body--

```
{
"d" : {
"__metadata": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Categories(0)",     "type": "ODataDemo.Category"
}, "ID": 97, "Name": "Food", "Products": [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Products(    0)", "type": "ODataDemo.Product"
}, "ID": 97, "Name": "Bread", "Description": "Whole grain bread", "ReleaseDate":      "\/Date(694224000000)\/", "DiscontinuedDate": null, "Rating": 4, "Price": "2.5", "Category": {
"__deferred": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Products(0)/Category"
}
}, "Supplier": {
"__deferred": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Products(0)/Supplier"
}
}
}
]
}
}
```

and I get the 400 Bad request with error description:

```
{
error: {
code: ""
message: {
lang: "en-US"
value: "Error processing request stream. The property name 'd' specified for type 'ODataDemo.Category' is not valid."
}-
}-
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to append "d" in the body of post request.
Remove the "d" and send the body like this:

```
{
"__metadata": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Categories(0)",     "type": "ODataDemo.Category"
}, "ID": 97, "Name": "Food", "Products": [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Products(    0)", "type": "ODataDemo.Product"
}, "ID": 97, "Name": "Bread", "Description": "Whole grain bread", "ReleaseDate":      "\/Date(694224000000)\/", "DiscontinuedDate": null, "Rating": 4, "Price": "2.5", "Category": {
"__deferred": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Products(0)/Category"
}
}, "Supplier": {
"__deferred": {
"uri":"http://services.odata.org/(S(egpbfjhhvili4slwaq1p2lvt))/V2/odata/OData.svc/Products(0)/Supplier"
}
}
}
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) It was also that my payload contained a "results" tag which had to be removed.